# Why does auto not work with some lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

Given the function:

```
void foo(std::function<void(int, std::uint32_t, unsigned int)>& f)
{
    f(1, 2, 4);
}
```

Why does this compile:

```
std::function<void(int a, std::uint32_t b, unsigned int c)> f =
    [] (int a, std::uint32_t b, unsigned int c) -> void
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
    return;
};
```

And this fails to compile:

```
auto f =
    [] (int a, std::uint32_t b, unsigned int c) -> void
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
    return;
};
```

With the error:

```
5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo(f);
    ^~~
6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at...:9)' to 'std::function<void (int, std::uint32_t, unsigned int)> &' for 1st argument 
void foo(std::function<void(int, std::uint32_t, unsigned int)>& f)
     ^
```

Comment: Have you tried with different compilers? It's a good idea to try with both clang and gcc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A lambda is not a `std::function`. Thus, calling the `foo` function requires construction of a temporary `std::function` object from the lambda, and passing this temporary as an argument. However, the `foo` function expects a modifiable lvalue of type `std::function`. Obviously, a prvalue temporary can't be bound by a non-const lvalue reference. Take *by value* instead:

```
void foo(std::function<void(int, std::uint32_t, unsigned int)> f)
{
    f(1, 2, 4);
}
```

Comment: capturing by `const&` should be working as well, right?